# Upper bound for the $n$-th derivative of a rational function $\frac{f}{f+g}$

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, polynomials, inequalities, rational-functions

Let $f$ and $g$ be real polynomials with nonnegative coefficients. Let
$$
h = \frac{f}{f+g}.
$$
I want to prove that the $n$-th derivative of $h$ satisfies:

> There exists $C > 0$ such that
> $$
> |h^{(n)}(x)| \le Cn!\frac{1}{x^n}, \qquad n \ge 0,\ x > 0.
> $$

Is it a known result? The problem seems rather simple at first glance, but I am stuck. It is easy to prove the above inequality holds with $C = C(n)$ depending on $n$. In this case, for example, we can use the Leibniz rule combined with induction.

I checked multiple cases numerically and the conjecture looks to be true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are counterexamples. Indeed, assume that the claimed bound holds for $x=1$. Then the Taylor series of $h(z)$ around $z=1$ converges in the disk $D=\{z:|z-1|<1\}$, hence $h(z)$ is analytic in $D$. However, the rational function $h(z)=1/(1+z^4)$ has a pole at $e^{\pi i/4}\in D$, contradiction.

Comment: Nice (counter)example! Are there any sufficient conditions on $f$ and $g$ that could guarantee the existence of such $C$?

Comment: @xen Sure. A sufficient condition is that $h(z)$ is bounded in the half-plane $\{z:\Re z\geq 0\}$. This follows from Cauchy's integral formula applied to the circles $\{z:|z-x|\leq x\}$.

Comment: @GHfromMO This is almost a necessary condition too. Actually, a necessary and sufficient condition is that $h$ does not have any pole with positive real value. That it is necessary is the argument in your answer for $x \to \infty$; to check it is sufficient it is enough (Partial fraction decomposition) to check it for $h(z) = 1/(z-a)^k$ for $k\geq 0$ and $a\neq 0$ with nonnegative real part.

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle Nice observation! BTW your last sentence should end with "nonpositive real part".

Comment: @GHfromMO Of course, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thank you both for so valuable explanation.